# How should I inteprete this anova result?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, anova

[image]

I sas this example in the book R in action, the codes in R are as follows:

```
library(multcomp)
attach(cholesterol)
table(trt)
trt
aggregate(response, by=list(trt), FUN=mean)
aggregate(response, by=list(trt), FUN=sd)
fit<-aov(response ~ trt)
summary(fit)

tuk<-glht(fit, linfct=mcp(trt="Tukey"))
plot(cld(tuk, level=.05), col="lightgrey")
```

It is written in the book that:

> From these results, you can see that taking the cholesterol-lowering
>   drug in 5 mg doses four times a day was better than taking a 20 mg
>   dose once per day. The competitor drugD wasn’t superior to this
>   four-times-per-day regimen. But competitor drugE was superior to both
>   drugD and all three dosage strategies for our focus drug

What I understund is:

four times a day is better than one time a day, because the mean is higher.  (mean is the right value to watch, isn't?)

DurgE is the best among all, because of the mean.

What I could not understand is:

1. Why is four times a day better than drugD? The mean of drugD is higher.
2. How could four times a day be compared with drugD? They are not signifikantlly different. (they both have the alphabet c in this graphic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@yue86231 I think you've simply misread the R manual.  The book (as you've quoted) states that DrugD WASN'T (significantly) better than the 4x/day regimen.  As you indicated, the post-hoc letters above the plot indicate a shared letter (c).

Comment: So "The competitor drugD wasn’t superior to this four-times-per-day regimen" can also be written as:  "drugD wasn't significantly better than four time a day, even though the mean of drugD is higher than four times a day". Now I understand it, thanks!